# How can I check whether is a string contains only English letters?

Tags: php, regex, string

I use PHP and I need to check whether is a string made of just

- English Lowercase letter
- dash
- underline?

Something like this:

```
if ( /* the condition */ ) {
    // Yes, all characters of the string are English lowercase letters or dash or underline
} else {
    // No, there is at least one unexpected character
}
```

Here is some examples:

```
$str = "test";   // true
$str = "test_-'; // true
$str = "t-s";    // true
$str = "test1";  // false
$str = "Test";   // false
$str = "test?";  // false
```

Comment: `^[a-z_-]+$` should do it for you

Comment: The letters you are referring to are called [Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) letters. Many character sets have other letters that are used in English text (which include English alphabetic characters with diacritics, tildes, accents, cedillas, ligatures and also certain apostrophes etc are considered letters in some character sets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a *whole* string that only consists of 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters, hyphen or underscores, use

```
/^[-a-z_]+$/D
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mV4eN9/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[-a-z_]+` - 1 or more ASCII lowercase letters, hyphens or underscores
- `$`  - end of string
- `/D` - the modifier that will make `$` match the *very end* of the string (otherwise, `$` will also match a newline that appears at the end of the string).

PHP:

```
if (preg_match('/^[-a-z_]+$/D', $input)) {
    // Yes, all characters of the string are English lowercase letters or dash or underline
} else {
    // No, there is at least one unexpected character
}
```

Comment: upvoted ... I guess you're trying to be the first one as regex top-user `;-)`

Comment: I am not trying anything, just trying to follow the [*The first thing you should do after reading someone's answer to your question is vote on the answer, like any other user (with sufficient reputation) does. Vote up answers that are helpful and well-researched, and vote down answers that are not. Other users will also vote on answers to your question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) guidelines. BTW, I (almost) always upvote the questions I answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP function

```
preg_match()
```

with this regular expression:

```
$regex = [a-z\_\-]+
```

The \ are to escape out the underscore and dash. + means you have to have at least 1 character.

This is a handy tool for regular expressions http://www.regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size

```
/**
 * Test if a string matches our criteria
 */
function stringTestOk($str) {
   return !(preg_match_all('/[^a-z_\-]/', $str) > 0);
}      

// Examples
foreach(['test', 'test_-', 't-s', 'test1', 'Test', 'test?'] as $str) {
   echo $str, ' ', (stringTestOk($str) ? 'true' : 'false'), PHP_EOL;
}
```